# Select column name dynamically mySQL Query

Tags: query, sql

```
$country="USA";
$dr=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT $country FROM wp_shipping WHERE ID=$ids");
```

I want the above query in WordPress file, where country name is given dynamically but I am not getting how to do this. When I execute the above query, the result is nothing.

Comment: your SQL is wrong, and it is more of an SQL question then a wordress one. The way I debug SQL is by running queries in phpmyadmin when I think that my code should work but it doesn't.

Comment: I am using this query in wordpress that is why i have asked this question here. And i want help that where i am wrong?

Comment: told you where you are wrong, and I want to date a super model :). Basically if it is not related to understanding the usage of wordress API then the question will have a better chance of being answered in other places. in your case you need an SQL help not a wordpress help.

Comment: Please follow up answers to your questions.

Comment: @  kaiser ofcourse i'll but i don't why are u pointing me here

Comment: Please follow up on the questions you asked, it's an important part of the process on WPSE - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for a deeper insight. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess one could argue that this is somewhat wordpress related, because you are trying to `get_results()` from `$wpdb`, but like @MarkKaplun said your problem is that you are using the SQL wrong. Below code is an *example* on how to do it correct:

```
$dr = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM wp_shipping WHERE country = %s AND ID = %d",
        $country, $ids
    )
);
```

This is an *example*, you might have to fit it to your needs. For additional information you should take a closer look at the codex [Class Reference: wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).